# Excel 2007 macro get selected rows

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get the rows which are already selected by a user in an excel sheet using macros. How should I do that?

I have attached an image. I have selected row number 3. I want to get that selected row in a macro. If the user selects more than one row, I want to get all those selected rows in the macro.

[image: Selected row in excel sheet]

Comment: U want selected row that means you want the copy of the rows to be pasted somewhere in excel ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Selection` will get the current selected range.

```
Sub test()

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Selection

         'Will return address of selected range
        MsgBox rng.Address

        'will return row num
       Msgbox rng.Row

       'will give start row
       MsgBox "Start Row : " & rng.Row

      'will give end row
        MsgBox "End Row : " & rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1

    End Sub
```

Comment: And if the user selects more than one row?

Comment: **Selection** will pick up all selected rows.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Exactly :)